# Buyers structure by registration date query optimisation

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I would like to show buyers structure by their registration date e.g.:

```
H12016 10.000 buyers
```

from which

```
2.000 registered in H12014

4.000 registered in H22014
```

etc.

I have two queries for that:

Number 1 (buyers from H12016 (about 50k records)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
r.idUsera as id_usera

FROM
rezerwacje r

WHERE
r.dataZalozenia between '2016-01-01' and '2016-07-01'
and r.`status` = 'zabookowana'

ORDER BY
id_usera
```

Number 2 (users_ids and their registration (insert) date (about 3,8M users)):

```
SELECT
m.user_id,
date(m.action_date) as data_insert

FROM
mwids m

WHERE
m.`type` = 'insert'
```

Both queries separately run fine, but when I try to combine them like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
r.idUsera as id_usera,
t1.data_insert

FROM
rezerwacje r

LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
    m.user_id,
    date(m.action_date) as data_insert

    FROM
    mwids m

    WHERE
    m.`type` = 'insert'
    ) t1 ON t1.user_id = r.idUsera

WHERE
r.dataZalozenia between '2016-01-01' and '2016-07-01'
and r.`status` = 'zabookowana'

ORDER BY
id_usera
```

this query runs "indefinetely" and I have to kill it after some time.

I do not belive it should run that long. If the query Number 2 was smaller i.e. about 1M users I could combine results in Excel in matter of seconds. So why is it not possible inside the database? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Bug:  `BETWEEN` is inclusive.  Change to `date >= '2016-01-01' AND date < '2016-01-01' + 12 MONTH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
r.idUsera as id_usera,
t1.data_insert

FROM
rezerwacje r

INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
    m.user_id,
    date(m.action_date) as data_insert

    FROM
    mwids m

    WHERE
    m.`type` = 'insert'
    ) t1 ON t1.user_id = r.idUsera

WHERE
r.dataZalozenia between '2016-01-01' and '2016-07-01'
and r.`status` = 'zabookowana'

ORDER BY
id_usera
```

Try with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Indeed it did!! Thank you!
But can you please help me understand why? What was my mistake?

Comment: @radek As far as,if you put `LEFT JOIN` it will make comparison of every row of  `rezerwacje` table with every row of  inner table `t1` in our case.So if i put `INER JOIN` then it's only compare those rows which are equal with `INNER TABLE t1`.

Comment: but with INNER JOIN I don't get NULLs for users that do not have insert_date and there are some users like that, do I?

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 needs

```
INDEX(status, dataZalozenia, id_usera)
```

Query 3: Rewrite thus:

If there is only one row in mwids for 'insert' per user:

```
SELECT  r.idUsera as id_usera, DATE(m.action_date) AS data_insert
    FROM  rezerwacje r
    LEFT JOIN  mwids m  ON m.user_id = r.idUsera
      AND  m.`type` = 'insert'
    WHERE  r.dataZalozenia >= '2016-01-01'
      AND  r.dataZalozenia  < '2016-01-01' + 12 MONTH
      and  r.`status` = 'zabookowana'
    ORDER BY  r.idUsera
```

with

```
INDEX(status, dataZalozenia, isUsera)   --  on r
INDEX(type, user_id, action_date)       --  on m
```

If there can be multiple rows, do this:

```
SELECT  r.idUsera as id_usera, 
        ( SELECT  DATE(m.action_date)
            FROM  mwids m
            WHERE  m.user_id = r.idUsera
              AND  m.`type` = 'insert'
            LIMIT  1 
        ) AS data_insert
    FROM  rezerwacje r
    LEFT JOIN  mwids m  ON m.user_id = r.idUsera
      AND  m.`type` = 'insert'
    WHERE  r.dataZalozenia >= '2016-01-01'
      AND  r.dataZalozenia <  '2016-01-01' + 12 MONTH
      and  r.`status` = 'zabookowana'
    ORDER BY  r.idUsera
```

But you will be getting a random action_date.  So maybe you want `MIN()` or `MAX()`?